# Vim color scheme installed with Vundle not changing colors

Tags: vim, color-scheme, iterm

I am trying to use one of the [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim) color schemes on a remote computer in Vim, but whenever I try to load any of the colorschemes, it doesn't seem to change. Vim's default colorschemes work fine.

Information about my setup:

- Using iTerm2, Build 1.0.0.20140112 (the most recent version)
- Using a base16 colorscheme on iTerm2
- In iTerm2's preferences, I have `xterm-256color` chosen for the "Report Terminal Type" field.
- Using zsh as my shell
- Vim is launched without any arguments

Here's the relevant settings in my `.vimrc` file:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax enable

set t_Co=256

" Access colors present in 256 colorspace
let base16colorspace=256

colorscheme base16-ocean
set background=dark
```

My Vundle settings are at the very top of `.vimrc`, before any of the other settings in the file settings.

Here's a few images that explain what is happening. In the first two images, I have applied a base16 color scheme, with no change in the colors shown in Vim. In the third, I have applied the preinstalled color scheme `delek` which results in a change of color.

[image: base16-3024]
[image: base16-ocean]
[image: delek]

Comment: Hello, I know it is quite an old question and it may be quite late to ask but was this happening even with using [base16-iterm2](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-iterm2)?

Comment: @ryuichiro Yes, and I believe I tried both 'base16-ocean.dark.256.itermcolors' and 'base16-ocean.dark.itermcolors' without success.

Answer (score 0):

Just change a color scheme in iTerm2 ;)

All schemes in base16 are the same (if in vimrc: t_Co=16) and if you change a color scheme in iTerm - vim colors will change too.